# using curve_fit (python) with a gaussian function which gives you mean and variance

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I have a problem with using `curve_fit` from `scipy`. Or at least it dosen't work the way that I expect it to work.

I have some kind of dataset from a histogram and the x-values are the sizes from the histogram as a numpy array. If needed, I will add my data later. The histogram has pretty much a Gaussian shape and I want to fit a Gauss function to it with only two free parameters, but it don't work.

With three parameters the code works fine:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 

hist=np.load('Rinnen.npy') 
faktor = np.sum(hist)

norm_hist=hist/faktor # values from the histogram are normed

ref_werte = np.arange(0,1,0.001)

def gauss(x, *p):
  a, b, c = p
  y = a*np.exp(-0.5*((x - b)/c)**2.)

  return y

p_initial = [0.1, 0.0, 0.1] 

popt, pcov = curve_fit(gauss, ref_werte, norm_hist, p0=p_initial)

print(popt) #zeigen der koeffizienten

plt.figure()
plt.plot(ref_werte, norm_hist, linewidth=2.0, color='b')
plt.plot(ref_werte, gauss(ref_werte, *popt), 'b-', linewidth=2.0, color='r')
plt.xlabel('Reflektanzen') 
plt.ylabel('normierte Häufigkeit')
plt.show()
```

But my goal is do use a Gaussian which is the PDF of a normal distributen (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)). But when I change my code and use a new definition of a function like the following one it messes up everything and don't work at all.

```
def gauss(x, *p):
  b, c = p
  kons = np.sqrt(2.*np.pi)
  y = (1./(c*kons))*np.exp(-0.5*((x - b)/c)**2.)

  return y
```

Even if I use for the `p_initial` values that are really close to the histogram like `p_initial = [0.08 , 0.02]` nothing works and I really don't understand why.

Would be really happy if someone could help me.

**EDIT: A code example**

One example array for `hist` is:

```
array([    0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     4,
          30,   224,  2257,  3603,  2029,  2412,  1391,  2269,  3789,
        8279,  9091,  6617,  7087,  5071,  2316,  2675,  2273,  3913,
        2299,  3573,  1761,  2445,  2426,  3261,  5881,  8408, 11659,
       15174, 21250, 19644, 32068, 25315, 19329, 23333, 17168, 15748,
       15744, 15045, 14274, 11566, 13887, 10144,  8532, 10696,  8531,
        9687,  9493,  9424, 10294,  8869,  9509,  8445,  7723,  8515,
        7137,  7464,  8006,  6440,  6457,  4999,  5364,  4519,  4361,
        3976,  3366,  3352,  2833,  2475,  2332,  1881,  1905,  1639,
        1568,  1318,  1141,  1130,  1010,   907,   906,   823,   789,
         745,   726,   674,   692,   630,   610,   568,   575,   589,
         535,   538,   522,   511,   513,   534,   467,   446,   445,
         337,   441,   454,   451,   438,   417,   388,   456,   405,
         408,   399,   356,   404,   371,   412,   404,   401,   389,
         354,   342,   358,   317,   306,   303,   295,   303,   294,
         288,   251,   256,   226,   178,   241,   213,   196,   215,
         210,   184,   165,   208,   200,   181,   171,   136,   156,
         147,   137,   102,   119,   116,    89,   117,   104,    85,
          77,    74,    52,    69,    34,    47,    44,    50,    32,
          27,    34,    38,    24,    21,    28,    24,    22,    25,
          19,    17,    15,    17,    18,    14,    11,    12,     5,
           9,     9,     9,     6,     5,     5,     8,     7,     4,
           4,     2,     1,     4,     0,     2,     2,     2,     3,
           2,     3,     1,     1,     2,     1,     2,     2,     0,
           1,     1,     2,     1,     1,     2,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     1,     1,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     1,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           1,     0,     0,     0,     1,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0])
```

With this array my code works with the version with three parameters and I get `[ 0.02697915  0.08060284  0.01334016]` as a result. If I change my code to the two parameter version with the same array and everything in the same way... then it doesn't fit and work at all. I used an other version of `p_initial = [0.08 , 0.02]`, which uses the mean and the standard derivation the result is not true at all: `[-1.62281493  0.53329897]`.

Comment: If the mean is near 0.08 then having `np.arange(0,1,0.001)` as the bin centers does not make sense.

Comment: Maybe yon can create a [mcve] with a sample of your data.

Comment: I've added it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal distribution is a continuous distribution, therefore you mustn't normalize the sum of your histogram, but the integral.

Here is a version of your code that works for me. The only thing I changed is dividing your histogram by the bin width. It returns `[ 0.08083458  0.01470529]`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 


hist = np.array([    0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     4,
          30,   224,  2257,  3603,  2029,  2412,  1391,  2269,  3789,
        8279,  9091,  6617,  7087,  5071,  2316,  2675,  2273,  3913,
        2299,  3573,  1761,  2445,  2426,  3261,  5881,  8408, 11659,
       15174, 21250, 19644, 32068, 25315, 19329, 23333, 17168, 15748,
       15744, 15045, 14274, 11566, 13887, 10144,  8532, 10696,  8531,
        9687,  9493,  9424, 10294,  8869,  9509,  8445,  7723,  8515,
        7137,  7464,  8006,  6440,  6457,  4999,  5364,  4519,  4361,
        3976,  3366,  3352,  2833,  2475,  2332,  1881,  1905,  1639,
        1568,  1318,  1141,  1130,  1010,   907,   906,   823,   789,
         745,   726,   674,   692,   630,   610,   568,   575,   589,
         535,   538,   522,   511,   513,   534,   467,   446,   445,
         337,   441,   454,   451,   438,   417,   388,   456,   405,
         408,   399,   356,   404,   371,   412,   404,   401,   389,
         354,   342,   358,   317,   306,   303,   295,   303,   294,
         288,   251,   256,   226,   178,   241,   213,   196,   215,
         210,   184,   165,   208,   200,   181,   171,   136,   156,
         147,   137,   102,   119,   116,    89,   117,   104,    85,
          77,    74,    52,    69,    34,    47,    44,    50,    32,
          27,    34,    38,    24,    21,    28,    24,    22,    25,
          19,    17,    15,    17,    18,    14,    11,    12,     5,
           9,     9,     9,     6,     5,     5,     8,     7,     4,
           4,     2,     1,     4,     0,     2,     2,     2,     3,
           2,     3,     1,     1,     2,     1,     2,     2,     0,
           1,     1,     2,     1,     1,     2,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     1,     1,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     1,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           1,     0,     0,     0,     1,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0])

faktor = np.sum(hist)

ref_werte = np.arange(0,1,0.001)

bin_width = 0.001

norm_hist=hist/(bin_width*faktor) # values from the histogram are normed

def gauss(x, *p):
  b, c = p
  kons = np.sqrt(2.*np.pi)
  y = (1./(c*kons))*np.exp(-0.5*((x - b)/c)**2.)

  return y

p_initial = [0, 1] 

popt, pcov = curve_fit(gauss, ref_werte, norm_hist, p0=p_initial)

print(popt) #zeigen der koeffizienten

plt.figure()
plt.plot(ref_werte, norm_hist, linewidth=2.0, color='b')
plt.plot(ref_werte, gauss(ref_werte, *popt), 'b-', linewidth=2.0, color='r')
plt.xlabel('Reflektanzen') 
plt.ylabel('normierte Häufigkeit')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I will use the results of code to compare different histograms to each other... therefore it is important to norm it.

Comment: @Mara I think you misunderstand. I'm not saying you shouldn't normalize. What I'm saying is I suspect you do not normalize correctly. You seem to normalize in such a way that the *sum* becomes 1. That is not correct. You want the *integral* to be 1, meaning that you must take the bin width into consideration.

Comment: Ah, yes. I misunderstood you. But the error is the same in both versions and I think it doesn't explain why one version work and the other not.

Comment: @Mara It does actually explain the difference: in your 3-parameter fit the scale is one of the fit parameters (a). So in this case even if you got the scaling wrong the fit procedure will just compensate by adjusting a. In the 2-parameter version this is not possible. Anyway, for me dividing your histogram by `0.001` works, see updated post. HTH

Comment: Ok, thank you. :) Think I need to read a little bit about this normalization.